# Nexus 5 Windows 8.1 Connection Issue

Tags: usb, nexus-5, connection-issues, windows

I have a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 running Windows 8.1 64bit.
Upon connecting my Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 via USB, the device seems to keep connecting and disconnecting repeatedly. I don't have the chance to go to the Device Manager to update the driver.

I have a similar problem under Ubuntu 14.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the same thing happens on another operating system, the problem is not the driver. It sounds like a power issue or the connector is not seating well on one of the two ends. See if a different cable helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
I've tried swapping cables, tried different ports and computers.Ubuntu issue was experienced on a different PC.